# App crashes in some version of the android mobiles

Tags: android, crash, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I made an app and launched successfully in the play store.
One of my friends said that the app was not working for him.

I checked that my app was not working below android 6.0: it just crashes and stops working.
It works fine in other devices.

There is no error.
Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: By no errors do you mean no stack track?

Comment: Yes ,it is ,i checked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved the problem:**

I accidentally deleted a layout file for an activity and only v-24 version layout file is on that app for that activity, so it made my app crash on lower version devices, now after creating that deleted layout, It work fine now.

hope my answer help you guys.

thank you.

Comment: So it was a versioning problem? You accidentally removed your support for earlier versions..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your application is not designed very well for backward compatibility. I suggest reading through Android's developer training on creating your application with backward compatibility.

https://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui

If you do not want to do this, you might need to restrict the **minSdkVersion** in your **build.gradle** file. I don't know what it is set to now for your app but this might help with not having to support earlier versions. Android provides a table for versions and API levels that will help in deciding a minimum.

https://source.android.com/setup/build-numbers

If you want more detailed help, you will need to supply a lot more context to your question.

Answer (score 0):

1) if you launched your app on play store then look at developer console in app page for error log. You can monitor what causes the crash .

2) The crash may because you used any deprecated methods which is removed in latest version of android.

Comment: Okay I'll check